# Save file with windows path system in linux file structure

Tags: linux, spring, windows, path

My spring application is running on a tomcat server under Windows system and saves files to path C:\pathtoSav (file = new File("C:\upload\" + filename)).

I want to migrate my application on a tomcat server under Linux system.
Can I create this file with path on Linux system without change my code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your code. You have a few options:

1. Use a relative directory such as saving the file to the current directory. This will work on both systems.
2. Check the operating system using something like [`System.getProperty("os.name")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) and hardcode the path to what you need in each system (e.g. `C:\upload` in Windows and `/home/ubuntu/uploads` in Linux), selecting which one you want based on the OS.
3. Find a way to get a reasonable path on any OS, such as [`System.getProperty("user.home")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) which will always return the user's directory for the operating system.

If you need to build paths yourself, Java has [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) as a convenience, which will be a forward slash on *nix and a backslash on Windows.